# Input field data not deleted once add

Tags: javascript, cakephp-3.0

I have a form which is including with cakephp3 and JS.
I have a question how can i store data into the input field?
There is some condition for this task, if once user add input into the input field these data will not remove , if the page is load by someone or close the browser and again get back to that page user will get same data in input field what he type, but when he submit the form then only data will remove from the form. any possible solution for this.

Comment: Maybe store the input.value on localStorage until the user submits the data? Then delete localstorage and reset the input field data to an empty string after that?

Comment: yes something like that.

Comment: But what event should we listen for? I am assuming you have only 1 submit button which would post the form? Otherwise you would need a second button which would save the data to local storage. Otherwise I cannot think of a way to store the data in local storage just by the user typing in and pressing nothing.

Comment: i am trying that when user keyup or keydown on the input field then the data submit it directly and when they submit the form then it will remove and the form become fresh again

Comment: Try the code below.

Comment: Did the code do what you wanted? :)

Comment: hi @WizardOfOz i found the solution by storing the value first on local storage then when i submit the form it will delete, first took the value from the input field and store into the local store and then when i submit the value will get vanish, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can handle this by;

1. Saving the input.value to localstorage
2. Set your input value to whatever is in local storage
3. On submit you clear localstorage

   // Get the input field
   let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
   let submit = document.getElementById('submit');

   ```
   // Save data to local storage on keyup or keydown
   input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
     if (e.key === 'ArrowUp' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      localStorage.setItem('Name', JSON.stringify(input.value))
     }
   });

   //Populate input data with whatever is in localstorage
   function populateUI(){
       if (localStorage.getItem("Name") !== null) {
         input.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Name'))
       }  
   }

   // Reset localstorage and input field value after submit
   submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("Name");
      input.value = ''
   }, false)

   populateUI();
   ```